# Not Exists query

Tags: sql

I'm trying to find the clients, those who didn't order in the last 2 years  and they ordered this year more than 500.. I wrote this query and I used the "NOT EXISTS" condition, but it is still showing me the wrong results.
Some suggestions would be appreciated.

My code:

```
SELECT
         "Sales"."Kundennummer" as 'Neuer Kunde',
         year("Sales"."Datum"),
         sum("Sales"."Umsatz mit Steuer") as "Umsatz"
FROM  "Sales" 
WHERE year("Sales"."Datum")  = '2017'
 AND NOT EXISTS
    (
    SELECT "Sales"."Kundennummer"
    FROM  "Sales" 
    WHERE    year("Sales"."Datum")  = '2015'
     AND    year("Sales"."Datum")  = '2016'
    )
GROUP BY
 "Sales"."Kundennummer",
      "Sales"."Datum" 
HAVING sum("Sales"."Umsatz mit Steuer")  > 500
```

Comment: Edit your post and add the database concern please.

Comment: I think that you should use `OR` instead of `AND` when comparing with 2015 and 2016. The year can't be 2015 and 2016 at the same time

Comment: The query still show me wrong result

Comment: @Karim see Tobb's answer, you're still missing a link between main query and subquery

Comment: NOT EXISTS sub-queries are generally correlated.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?  "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 1):

The query in the `NOT EXISTS` clause will probably yield 0 rows, since a row can't have `Datum` both `2015` and `2016`. So it should probably be `OR` instead of `AND`.

Also, if you fix this, there is no link between the subquery and the superquery, which means that it will return rows for any customer (given that there exists a row with Datum either 2015 or 2016 in your table which I guess it does).

So, something like:

```
SELECT
         "Sales"."Kundennummer" as 'Neuer Kunde',
         year("Sales"."Datum"),
         sum("Sales"."Umsatz mit Steuer") as "Umsatz"
FROM  "Sales" sales
WHERE year("Sales"."Datum")  = '2017'
 AND NOT EXISTS
    (
    SELECT "Sales"."Kundennummer"
    FROM  "Sales" salesI
    WHERE salesI."Kundennummer" = sales."Kundennummer"
      AND (year("Sales"."Datum")  = '2015'
           OR year("Sales"."Datum")  = '2016')
    )
GROUP BY
 "Sales"."Kundennummer",
      "Sales"."Datum" 
HAVING sum("Sales"."Umsatz mit Steuer")  > 500
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `EXISTS` query is not correlated to the main query, i.e. it doesn't look for data for the `Kundennummer` in question, but whether there are *any*  records in 2015 and 2016.

(You also have the condition for the years wrong by using `AND` where it must be `OR` and you should not use quotes on numbers like `2015'`, and you should not use single quotes on names like `'Neuer Kunde'`.)

It should be

```
AND NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM Sales other_years
  WHERE other_years.Kundennummer = Sales.Kundennummer
    AND year(other_years.Datum) in (2015, 2016)
)
```

or uncorrelated with `NOT IN`

```
AND Kundennummer NOT IN
(
  SELECT Kundennummer
  FROM  Sales
  WHERE year(Datum) in (2015, 2016)
)
```

Be aware though, that when using `NOT IN` the subquery must return no nulls. E.g. `where 3 not in (1, 2, null)` does not result in true, as one might expect, because the DBMS argues that the unknown value (null) might very well be a 3 :-)

Comment: The result of a `NOT IN` query may surprise many people if the sub-query returns a null value.

Comment: @jarlh: Yes, I should have mentioned this. It's just that it is so rare that you look up values that can be null. Kundennummer means customer number and this should never be null in a sales record. Hence no problem here, but I'll add the warning.

Answer (score 0):

I propose you here below 3 different ways to do it:

1. Joining 2 tables

   ```
   select this_year_sales.kundenummer, this_year_sales.tot_umsatz
   from (select sum(umsatz) tot_umsatz, kundenummer from sales where extract(year from (datum)) = extract(year from sysdate) group by kundenummer) this_year_sales
   , (select kundenummer, max(datum) max_datum from sales where datum < trunc(sysdate, 'year') group by kundenummer) previous_sales
   where this_year_sales.kundenummer = previous_sales.kundenummer
   and extract(year from previous_sales.max_datum) < (extract(year from sysdate)-2) 
   and this_year_sales.tot_umsatz > 500;
   ```
2. Using NOT INT

   ```
   select kundenummer, sum(umsatz)
   from sales s
   where extract(year from datum) = extract(year from sysdate)
   and kundenummer not in (select kundenummer from sales where extract(year from datum) > (extract(year from sysdate) - 2) and extract(year from datum) < (extract(year from sysdate)-1))
   group by kundenummer
   having sum(umsatz) > 500;
   ```
3. Using NOT EXISTS

   ```
   select kundenummer, sum(umsatz)
   from sales s
   where extract(year from datum) = extract(year from sysdate)
   and not exists(
   select s1.kundenummer, s1.datum from sales s1 where extract (year from s1.datum) >= (extract(year from sysdate)-2) and extract(year from s1.datum) < extract (year from sysdate) and s1.kundenummer = s.kundenummer
   )
   group by kundenummer
   having sum(umsatz) > 500;
   ```